# Extract Camera Roll from iTunes backup

Tags: itunes, backup

I had to restore a friend's iPod because they forget their passcode and they lost their camera roll. I can't restore FROM a backup, as the backup has the forgotten passcode on it.

Anyways, on my Mac I looked under `~/library/application support/MobileSync/Backup` to find some hashed folder with a  boatload of hashed files and a couple .plist's saying it was indeed a backup.

My question is- I am sure these photos are in this folder hashed somewhere.. how can I get them out?

Thanks :)

Comment: What version of iPod? Some store photo thumbnails in a database instead of a hashed file folder structure. Knowing the version of iTunes and the OS you have to work with and the version and type of iOS device will make this both easier to answer and more useful to the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPhone Backup Viewer shows everything in the backup and will save the photos (and anything else) to the folder you specify.

Donation-ware at http://www.imactools.com/iphonebackupviewer/

Answer (score 1):

There are third-party applications such as iBackupViewer and iPhone Backup Extractor that will read those backup files.

Also, if by any chance Photostream was turned on, those photos are on somebody's Mac, hiding in

~/Library/Application Support/iLifeAssetManagement/assets/sub

Comment: Ah, noted. No.. Photo Stream wasn't on :(

Comment: Do you think renaming a random number of those files or .jpg or .png until one opens would work on no?

Comment: iPhone Backup Viewer shows you everything in the backup - apps, photos, etc. - and all can be saved to computer.

Answer (score -1):

Here I recommend you [MyJad iTunes Photo Extractor](http://www.myjad.com/itunes-photo-extractor.html)* to help you extract camera roll you want back.

[*]: Commercial software, trial available.

Comment: [*][*]: trial you mean extract 5 files